# Vuejs beforeRouteEnter not receiving data. Undefined

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I want to get data in vuejs before component is rendered. So this is the problem I don't get the data with beforeRouteEnter.

This is a **working** example with `created`:

```
created() {
    this.$store.dispatch('getInvite');
    this.$store.dispatch('getInviteUser');
},
computed: mapState([
    'user',
    'invite',
    'invite_user'
]),
```

And with this beforeRouteEnter I get `localhost:8080/invitation/undefined`

```
 beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
     store.dispatch('getInvite');
    next();
},
```

This is function in `actions.js`

```
const getInvite = ({
  commit
}) => {
  API.get('/invitation/' + router.currentRoute.params.slug + '/' + router.currentRoute.params.id)
    .then((response) => {
      if (response.status === 200 && response.data.invite && response.data.user) {
        return commit('SET_INVITE', response.data.invite);
      } else {
        return router.push({
          name: 'home'
        });
      }
    }).catch((error) => {
      return console.log(error);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**According to the doc :**

> The beforeRouteEnter guard does NOT have access to this, because the guard is called before the navigation is confirmed, thus the new entering component has not even been created yet.

So `router` is still undefined since it is a plugin for the instance :

instead you can use  `afterEach` where the instance is created and the new route is navigated :

**on your `router` file :**

```js
router.afterEach((to,from)=>{
     if (to == 'component') {
        store.dispatch('getInvite')
      }
    })
  // you don't have to use the if in case you want an API call after every navigation
```

**NB :** since `afterEach` is not an "In-Component Guard" you need to import your store to `router.js` file if you have the last one separated on its own folder

Comment: Well this works in strange behaviour. If I go from one invitation to another invitation I see info of the first invitation until I revisit the last invitation.

Comment: @zlotte yes because the `to` route is not navigated yet we are still o, `beforeRouteLeave` ... it is still on the one  that you went from ... if you don't necessarily need  a`beforeRoute` you can use  `afterEach` as i said ...so the destined router is navigated ..this should be the solution for your problem so i will update the answer with it.

Comment: I need to put this in router.js ?

Comment: Okay. I don't have `router`. I have `export default new Router` in my `router.js` file. Do I make an instance ?

Comment: @zlotte ok then put that under your import `import router from ''/router.js'`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197184/discussion-between-zlotte-and-dadboz).